# PHPExcel is not importing Excel sheet in Server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am trying to import data from a excel sheet using PHPExcel

my code lines are

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '5120MB');    
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Earlier in my local I used to get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)

I increased my memory_size in php.ini file from 128M to 256M and this functionality working fine in my local. So I did the same thing in my server but it's not working. I am using Ubuntu server.

Comment: By "not working", you mean you're getting the same "Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted"? Or something different?

Comment: I tried logging errors by changing the php.ini file error settings
Error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
error_log = /var/log/apache2/error.log

but it is not logging any errors into the log file. But this importing task is not happening in the server while it is quite good in my local

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is what you mean by "not working"? Do you get a blank page? Do you get any displayed messages? Does the webserver log show anything? Does anything get added to the database?

Comment: If the import occurs properly it should be added to both database and should be showed up in the webpage, both are not happening. I used try catch block around last two lines and echoed the message but my browser is not showing anything

Comment: Then you need to check logs: start with the webserver log, then php logging

Comment: php error logs are not showing anything. I dont know about where these webserver logs will reside. I will check it once, if you know the location please let me know

Comment: the webserver config files should identify where it's writing its logs

Comment: Whatever I made changes to my php.ini file it is not reflecting. is why it's not accepting that memory change it seems. Do you have any idea where other place that overrides the php.ini file configuration and gets loaded while loading the application?

Comment: @user3347454 Depnding on your configuration, you may need to restart your php and/or webserver process for the changes to be picked up.

Comment: I ran php -i | grep "Loaded" to get the currect loaded confguration file and I got the path as /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, I made necessary changes to that php.ini file and I restarted my webserver process by /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. Still my changes are not picking up

Comment: You realise that running PHP from the command line typically uses a different php.ini to the webserver, and the __cli__ in the folder name should have told you that `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` isn't the same as `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`... make your changes to the latter

Comment: when I run the command php -i | grep "Loaded" I am getting /etc/php5/cli/php.ini as loaded configuration but when I run www.example.com/phpinfo.php(example.com is just for example it doesn't exist) I am getting loaded configuration file as /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini I am confused about this and any help regarding this is appreciated

Comment: PHP has a different configuration file for running from the command line than from running in the web server.... this is quite common. Typically the timeout for scripts is 30 seconds for a webserver, but unlimited for the command line, memory may also be different, and there's no need to limit the size of $_POST vars for cli scripts

Answer (score 1):

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '5120MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
```

This is telling PHPExcel to use **5GB** (5120MB) of physical memory before it should start to use php://temp for cell caching

Any value you specify in the **memoryCacheSize** setting should be lower than the amount of physical memory that is available to PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (..){ 
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// For list 1
}
foreach(..){
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
// For list 2
}
 $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Otchet.xlsx');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');`enter code here`
        ob_end_clean();
        $objWriter->save('php://output



     $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Otchet.xlsx');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            ob_end_clean();
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
            exit;





They should be written separately
```